# generating treeview in Angular 2

Tags: angular, treeview

I am testing tree view in Angular 2. Currently, I am referring to http://plnkr.co/edit/vd9XXAQTHXxkCXaSjUHb. There are some parts I can't understand especially content-list.component.ts. Within li, there is class named 'tree__branch'. Is this already existing class? I completely can't get it about it. And there is variable named 'toggle' in the contentNode, but I can't find that variable in the contentNode inside Component, how we could come to use it? And my ultimate goal is to change the '-' and '+' into the icons. If someone is familiar with these things, could you give some guides?

```
<ol class="tree">
            <li *ngFor="#contentNode of contentNodes" class="tree__branch" [ngClass]="{'tree__branch--has-children': contentNode.HasChildren}">
                <a *ngIf="contentNode.HasChildren" (click)="contentNode.toggle=!contentNode.toggle" class="toggle">{{ !!contentNode.toggle ? '-' : '+' }}</a> {{ contentNode.Name }}
              <content-list *ngIf="contentNode.toggle" [startingNode]="contentNode.Id"></content-list>
            </li>
        </ol>
<div class="error" *ngIf="errorMessage">{{errorMessage}}</div>
```

Comment: What does "ultimate goal is to change the '-' and '+' into the icons" mean? The plunker doesn't run (might be only me, had some troubles already today running plunkers).

Comment: What I mean is that I do not like + and - for expanding and collapsing in the part {{ !!contentNode.toggle ? '-' : '+' }}. I would like to use images instead of + and -.

Comment: I can run it successfully.

Comment: I updated my answer. I believe you that it runs for you ;-) but it doesn't for me :-/

Comment: Thank you so much! it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

> `class="tree__branch"`

is just old-style plain HTML CSS class. You can use it for styling with CSS. It's not Angular related at all.

> toggle is just an attribute added to the data items loaded from `app/data.json` that indicates the opened/closed state of the node

To get icons instead of `+`/`-` text just use

```
<a *ngIf="contentNode.HasChildren" (click)="contentNode.toggle=!contentNode.toggle" class="toggle">
  <img src="expand.png" *ngIf="!!contentNode.toggle">
  <img src="collapse.png" *ngIf="!contentNode.toggle">
</a> {{ contentNode.Name }}
```

Comment: nice beard gunter!

Comment: Yup, I like it as well. I'm considering growing one for real :D Seems to be quite cold where you live? ;-) It's snowing here as well but my hat is not as warm as your scarf ;-)

Comment: There is no explicit variable 'toggle' inside contentNode, so I asked. Thank you for your response.

Comment: FYI,   [
  {"Id":1054,"Name":"Rugby League","HasChildren":true},
  {"Id":1056,"Name":"Football","HasChildren":true}
]

Comment: Yes, freezing! But I'm very happy with the scarf they gave me. You should grow a beard though, it looks majestic!